# Caching location based data cluster

Tags: php, mysql, sql, caching, geolocation

How to serve the search results from a particular location without querying the database again and again that holds millions of records?

We are having a database of billions of records with `latitude` and `longitude`. And it is growing every minute. And now, we need to serve those data to our mobile application. So we planned to show this in following categories.

1. Showing latest 10 inserted results:
   For this, we are using a table in which when every new record comes, we are inserting it into the queue table and removing the last value if it is greater than 10.
2. Showing the latest 10 results from the user location:
   For this, we need to aggregate the data and show to the local users every 5 mins and we can serve the same data to all users from that locality for 5 mins.

Now, i need help with,

1. How to divide the areas? For example, if i divide the world in form of squares, then i can serve same data for each square for next 5 mins. Is there  any algorithms to divide the areas in similar model using geo location or do you think that any other model better suits for this?
2. How and where to cache the content for each area to serve only for next 5 mins, and it need to refreshed with new data. Is there any caching algorithms present in DB itself or is there any other technique present for this? 
    For example, if we have areas A & B into 2 squares, and if a user from "A" requests a data, then we need to cache the result and need to serve with same result without querying the DB to all the users requesting  for next 5 mins from the same square "A" and need to refresh it after that. So that i can save server bandwidth. But how to do this?
   Any server caching? Temporary tables or How?

Please direct me on this. Or if you think that there is a better approach, please, please let me know. Any references are also greatly welcome. Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to revisit your indexing strategy.

Comment: @eggyal Do you think that just indexing will help this out?

Comment: A well-designed database with sensible indexing can often avoid any need to shard the data in the manner you describe.  I certainly suggest you investigate indexing before looking elsewhere.